# Disambiguate class-member in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, ambiguity, enable-if

Suppose I have this variadic base class-template:

```
template <typename ... Types>
class Base
{
public:
    // The member foo() can only be called when its template 
    // parameter is contained within the Types ... pack.

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<Contains<T, Types ...>::value>::type
    foo() {
        std::cout << "Base::foo()\n";
    }
};
```

The `foo()` member can only be called when its template-parameter matches at least one of the parameters of `Base` (the implementation of `Contains` is listed at the bottom at this post):

```
Base<int, char>().foo<int>(); // fine
Base<int, char>().foo<void>(); // error
```

Now I define a derived class that inherits twice from Base, using ***non-overlapping sets*** of types:

```
struct Derived: public Base<int, char>,
                public Base<double, void>
{};
```

I was hoping that when calling e.g.

```
Derived().foo<int>();
```

the compiler would figure out which base-class to use, because it is SFINAE'd out of the one that does not contain `int`. However, both GCC 4.9 and Clang 3.5 complain about an ambiguous call.

My question then is two-fold:

1. Why can't the compiler resolve this ambiguity (general interest)?
2. What can I do to make this work, without having to write `Derived().Base<int, char>::foo<int>();`? **EDIT:** GuyGreer showed me that the call is disambiguated when I add two using-declarations. However, since I'm providing the base-class for the user to inherit from, this isn't an ideal solution. If at all possible, I don't want my users to have to add those declarations (which can be quite verbose and repetitive for large type-lists) to their derived classes.

Implementation of `Contains`:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Pack>
struct Contains;

template <typename T>
struct Contains<T>: public std::false_type
{};

template <typename T, typename ... Pack>
struct Contains<T, T, Pack ...>: public std::true_type
{};

template <typename T, typename U, typename ... Pack>
struct Contains<T, U, Pack ...>: public Contains<T, Pack...>
{};
```

Comment: It's a manifestation of the general rule that names from different scopes do not overload in C++.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a simpler example:

```
template <typename T>
class Base2 {
public:
    void foo(T ) { }
};

struct Derived: public Base2<int>,
                public Base2<double>
{};

int main()
{
    Derived().foo(0); // error
}
```

The reason for that comes from the merge rules [class.member.lookup]:

> Otherwise (i.e., C does not contain a declaration of f or the resulting declaration set is empty), S(f,C) is
>   initially empty. If C has base classes, calculate the lookup set for f in each direct base class subobject Bi,
>   and merge each such lookup set S(f,Bi) in turn into S(f,C).
>   — [..]
>   — Otherwise, if the declaration sets of S(f,Bi) and S(f,C) differ, the merge is ambiguous...

Since our initial declaration set is empty (`Derived` has no methods in it), we have to merge from all of our bases - but our bases have differing sets, so the merge fails. However, that rule explicitly only applies if the declaration set of `C` (`Derived`) is empty. So to avoid it, we make it non-empty:

```
struct Derived: public Base2<int>,
                public Base2<double>
{
    using Base2<int>::foo;
    using Base2<double>::foo;
};
```

That works because the rule for applying `using` is

> In the declaration set, *using-declarations* are replaced by the set
>   of designated members that are not hidden or overridden by members of the derived class (7.3.3),

There's no comment there about whether or not the members differ - we effectively just provide `Derived` with two overloads on `foo`, bypassing the member name lookup merge rules.

Now, `Derived().foo(0)` unambiguously calls `Base2<int>::foo(int )`.

---

Alternatively to having a `using` for each base explicitly, you could write a collector to do them all:

```
template <typename... Bases>
struct BaseCollector;

template <typename Base>
struct BaseCollector<Base> : Base
{
    using Base::foo;
};

template <typename Base, typename... Bases>
struct BaseCollector<Base, Bases...> : Base, BaseCollector<Bases...>
{
    using Base::foo;
    using BaseCollector<Bases...>::foo;
};

struct Derived : BaseCollector<Base2<int>, Base2<std::string>>
{ };

int main() {
    Derived().foo(0); // OK
    Derived().foo(std::string("Hello")); // OK
}
```

In C++17, you can [pack expand `using` declarations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0195r2.html) also, which means that this can be simplified into:

```
template <typename... Bases>
struct BaseCollector : Bases...
{
    using Bases::foo...;
};
```

This isn't just shorter to write, it's also more efficient to compile. Win-win.

Comment: Thanks, I understand where the ambiguity comes from now. However, as I mentioned in the comment to GuyGreer's answer and in the edited question, this solution isn't very friendly to my users. I suppose that, if there's no easy workaround, I'll just have to document carefully.

Comment: @JorenHeit If you're willing to introduce one more class in the hierarchy, one that collects a set of `Base` instantiations, and have the user inherit from that one, you can make it work.

Comment: @jrok But then I'd have to know the types that `Base` will be instantiated with, wouldn't I?

Comment: @JorenHeit Provided a solution that does all the `using`s for you.

Comment: @Barry shouldn't you also bring in the `foo`s from `BaseCollector<Bases...>`? Also need something to stop the recursive inheritance.

Comment: @T.C. Fixed typo on stopping recursive inheritance. I don't need to bring in `BaseCollector<Bases...>::foo` since there's just one subtype of `Derived`, so there can't be conflict be conflicting declaration sets.

Comment: @Barry no, I meant in your `BaseCollector<Base, Bases...> ` specialization. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a806eae2503ad800

Comment: @T.C. Oh hmm. I think you're right. This compiles on both gcc and clang, but now i'm not sure it should.

Comment: @Barry What you have does compile, but it only brings in the `foo` from the first base in the list. That `using` shadows any `foo` in `BaseCollector<Bases...>`.

Comment: @T.C. Ohh! Picking `double` was just the wrong choice... `foo(0.0)` just called `Base<int>::foo(int )`...

Comment: If you are gonna use this as a canonical dupe target (yay), could you add the binary-tree log-depth instantiation using solution?  The linear template one sort of limits you to a short list of bases.

Answer (score 3):

Though I can't tell you in detail why it doesn't work as is, I added `using Base<int, char>::foo;` and `using Base<double, void>::foo;` to `Derived` and it compiles fine now.

Tested with `clang-3.4` and `gcc-4.9`

Comment: Thats interesting... +1. However, if at all possible, I don't want my users to have to add those using-declarations to their code when inheriting from the baseclass I'm providing. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: @JorenHeit I'm not sure why it makes sense to derive from `Base` twice.  Sure they're non-overlapping, but why not just derive from `Base<int,char,double,void>` directly?

Comment: @GuyGreer I'm providing another class for the user, let's call it `Special`, which is itself derived from `Base` using a reserved type (hidden from the user, so it's guaranteed that the user won't use this type, hence non-overlapping). It would be nice if it's possible to derive from both `Special` and `Base<Whatever...>`.

Comment: @JorenHeit you can always provide a `SpecialAndBase<Whatever...>` that derives from `Special` and `Base<Whatever...>` and adds the proper `using`s...

Comment: @T.C. Hm... that's not bad actually. And so obvious... Thanks!